What are some options for automatically provisioning virtual servers?
I operate a small web hosting company that sells shared hosting and virtual private servers to customers. We are currently utilising WHMCS to automate our processes and all products we offer are cPanel provisioned via WHMCS running on Ubuntu and KVM.
I am currently considering offering a further VPS product that does not have a control panel installed by default.
I am after a solution that will allow automatic provisioning in WHMCS that provides customers SSH access and the ability to install an operating system of their choice (from a pre-defined list of my choosing).
I am not really sure how to go about implementing this and what Linux OS is required.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Have you asked the provider?

This should be a comment, but its a bit long....
I can think of at least a dozen ways to implement this (there are probably more). However there is also great opportunity for making some very major mistakes. It is clear from your question that there is a skills gap between where you are and what paying customers should expect from you.
You might get answers here addressing one or two possible solutions but they will be the solutions that were right (or at least chosen) by the commentators - not the right solution for you/your customers. I don't believe you are well placed to assess the quality of answers here.
You don't just suggestions, you will need help planning, implementating and then supporting this going forward. Posts asking for free advice on the interent will only get you so far. You need an MSP. And what technology/platform you should be using will be shaped as much by your choice of MSP as your own requirements.
